# Странная (не)работа cURL вместе с socks5

Tags: php, curl, socks5

Перед тем как опишу проблему,скажу: я не силен в некоторых аспектах,поэтому проявите терпение)

Установил я сервер lighttpd ,к нему PHP 7.0.25 ,и к ним  curl 7.47.0
через консоль ,командой `curl -k --socks5-hostname socks.zaborona.help:1488 https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=1&v=3.0` 
получаю ответ от вк.Все работает.
Но когда я пытаюсь использовать `socks.zaborona.help:1488` в коде php:

```
var_dump(Send_url('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=1&v=3.0'));
function Send_url( $url )
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'socks5://socks.zaborona.help:1488');

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_error ($ch)){
        echo curl_errno($ch).":".curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}
```

мне возвращает ошибку curl #6 Could not resolve host: api.vk.com.
Если закоментить `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'socks5://socks.zaborona.help:1488');`
то ошибка остается.Если изменить адрес на другой(незаблокированый Украиной) то все работает нормально. подозрения падают на связку cURL.что делать и куда копать?

Answer (score 0):

И так.после танца бубна исправил все.
1 попробывал это,не помогло https://code.i-harness.com/ru/q/e40743

2 переустановил php-curl.

3 ряд наверняка лишних телодвижений ,прописывания 8.8.8.8 и 4.2.1.1

и вновь 1 пункт,после которого все заработало

Comment: Что значит "1 попробовал"?